# Avoid multiple upload of release artefact in nexus by Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, continuous-integration

I have a web project split in multiple maven artefacts.

Let say it is :

- A, a jar
- B, a jar
- C, a jar
- D, a war

So, D has a dependency on B and C. B has a dependency on A.

Those modules versions are not always synchroneous.

A can be on version 3-SNAPSHOT while B is still in version 5 with a dependency on A version 2.

I configured jenkins to cascade build B when A is built, D when B or C is built.
Those modules also get rebuilt when a change is detected in the git repository.
Artefacts are automatically deployed in nexus repository by a post-build action.

So, if I push in git a new version 3-SNAPSHOT of A, a 3-SNAPSHOT jar is built and pushed in nexus. But, because of Jenkins dependency, a new build of B version 2 (**release** version) is triggered. The build itself goes ok, but the deploy to nexus fails, as I do not allow redeploy of release artefacts.

How can I avoid this situation ? Not trying to upload to nexus when the artefact has a release version and this version already exists in nexus would be acceptable.

I am using Jenkins 1.480 and maven 3.0.4.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger parameterized build with https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin and add a parameter to job B.

Conditional build plugin might also help https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin